# TeeUI924.bpl Access violation adding serie in tchart delphi

Tags: delphi, teechart

Adding or editing a serie in a TChart causes Access violation in module TeeUI924.bpl.

Click on OK opens the TeeChart Gallery, but it is "empty" and each click on a tab generates the same error message.

[image: teeUI924 Access violation message]

[image: TChart gallery after access violation message]

I have Delphi 10.1 Berlin Version 24.0.25048.9432 and TChart 2018.

I've already had the problem with TChart 2017. I've removed it and installed TChart 2018. The problem seemed to be repaired, but came back after computer restart.

Thank you for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested TeeChart VCL/FMX Pro v2018.25 works fine in RAD 10.1 Berlin Update 2 (24.0.25048.9432) and everything seems to work fine for me here.
I've tested both the binary and the source code versions.
If you are using a TeeChart Standard commercial version, please tell me and I'll also test it.

To reinstall the TeeChart Pro components, you can run "TeeInstall.exe" from the install folder and select "No" if a dialog asks if you want to uninstall.

Also, if you have other 3rd party components, try unselecting them in the list of packages to check if the problem is caused by some conflict.

If you still find problems with it, the next attempt would be to completelly uninstall the TeeChart components and install them again.

If everything else failed, at this point I wouldn't discard the option of a broken IDE installation. So I would try a repair or a complete uninstall & reinstall.

Comment: My TeeChart version is "TeeChart Pro VCL FMX Source 2018.24".
I've tried quite everything (not uninstall / reinstall Rad studio yet), still fails.

Comment: A SourceCode license gives you access to the binary versions in the [client area](https://www.steema.com/login). You could try if it installs fine for you.